# Query works on MySQL workbench but not on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, view

I've been sending a mails on Laravel using a body from a database, everything was working just fine until i add a join function in the laravel query. When I'm typing my query on MySQL workbench i have one row returned as expected but not with laravel.

Welcome.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

     
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('xxxxxx@yyy.com', 'John Doe')
            ->subject('Welcome')
            ->markdown('mails.welcome')
            ->with([
                'name' => 'New User',
                'wMail' => DB::table('mails')
                            ->join('users', 'mails.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                            ->where([
                                ['mails.user_id', 'users.id'],
                                ['mails.name', 'Welcome Email']
                            ])->get(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

User.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the mails for a user.
     */
    public function mails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Mail::class);
    }
}
```

Mail.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Get the user for a mail.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

2022_03_07_111014_create_mails_table.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mails', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('object');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('mails');
    }
};
```

I also have 5 users in my database, and one mail corresponding to the following factory :

```
    'user_id' => 3,
    'name' => 'Welcome Email',
    'object' => 'Bienvenu sur UH-Lawyers',
    'body' => $this -> faker -> text(200)
```

welcome.blade.php :

```
@component('mail::message')
Hello {{$name}},

@if (count($wMail)>0)
    @foreach($wMail as $mail)
        {{$mail->body}}
    @endforeach
@else 
    No result 
@endif

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

So when I type this query on MySQL : SELECT body FROM Mails.mails join Mails.users on users.id = mails.user_id where users.id = mails.user_id and mails.name ="Welcome Email";
I have one row returned corresponding to the mail's body I expect. But when I'm sending my mail on Laravel, "No result" appears on my mail's body.
But when I change my Laravel's query from :

> ...->where([['mails.user_id', 'users.id'],...

to :

> ...->where([['mails.user_id', '3'],...

everything works just fine!!! I really don't get what the problem is...

Comment: there's a general typing error on `users.id` it should be `user.id`

Comment: @HassaanAli The table name is `users` though, so `users.id` seems correct

Comment: `['mails.user_id', 'users.id'],` is already in the join condition. You don't need it in the `where`. It also is wrong the way it currently is in the where. You have `['mails.user_id', 'users.id'],` which you expect it to compare the values of columns and in the following line you have `['mails.name', 'Welcome Email']` which you expect it to compare the value of A column to a literal value. This should have raised some red flags to you.

Comment: Yeah but the query works even if I have '['mails.name', 'Welcome Email']' but i change the users.id to just '3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `where` clause, the first item filters the column `mails.user_id` on the value `'users.id'` which is a string.

I'm guessing this is *not* what you intend to do. Assuming you want to filter that column on a specific user ID, you need to supply that actual value.

Usually, you can retrieve the current (logged in) user's ID with `Auth::user()->id`. So I suggest you update your `build()` method as follows:

```php
// Welcome.php

public function build()
{
    $currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;

    return $this->from('xxxxxx@yyy.com', 'John Doe')
        ->subject('Welcome')
        ->markdown('mails.welcome')
        ->with([
            'name' => 'New User',
            'wMail' => DB::table('mails')
                        ->join('users', 'mails.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->where('mails.user_id', '=', $currentUserId)
                        ->where('mails.name', '=', 'Welcome Email')
                        ->first(),
        ]);
}
```

If, however, you wish to pass in another specific user ID, then you'll need to use a constructor argument for that:

```php
// Welcome.php
// (imports, traits and comments removed for brevity)

namespace App\Mail;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    // ...

    protected int $userId;


    public function __construct(int $userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('xxxxxx@yyy.com', 'John Doe')
            ->subject('Welcome')
            ->markdown('mails.welcome')
            ->with([
                'name' => 'New User',
                'wMail' => DB::table('mails')
                    ->join('users', 'mails.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('mails.user_id', '=', $this->userId)
                    ->where('mails.name', '=', 'Welcome Email')
                    ->first(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

And then, when you create your `Welcome` mailable instance:

```php
$userId = 0; // TODO: Retrieve the user ID you need
Mail::to('your@recipient.here')->send(new Welcome($userId));
```

The relevant documentation can be found on that page: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#sending-mail

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me with the second solution given that i haven't implemented the authentification method yet !

Answer (score 0):

If that query workson MySQL, and you have no way to making it work in laravel with that Syntax, you can try to use Laravel's DB class, with the following syntax:

```
$awnser = DB::select('SELECT body FROM Mails.mails join Mails.users on users.id = mails.user_id where users.id = mails.user_id and mails.name ="Welcome Email"');
```

But you should use parameters instead of writing everything there:

```
$welcome = "Welcome Email";
$awnser = DB::select('SELECT body FROM Mails.mails join Mails.users on users.id = mails.user_id where users.id = mails.user_id and mails.name =:name', ['name' => $welcome]);
```

This solution may work for you.

Comment: This solution works indeed, but since the query works that way, isn't there any way to make it work just the way I was trying to type it ?

Comment: Yes there is a way to solve it, but when you mix so many things, in my opinion it is easier to do it in a query, you will be able to modify it and understand it more clearly.